# how to get user specified data with Asp.net Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I created MVC4 application with internet application template, added an API controller with authorize attribute.
How can I make api controller action return user specified data?

Currently I am using WebSecurity.GetUserID to get Userid, I have Userid in the data table.
After compiling the application, if I call api controller action first, I will have following error message:

> You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call
>   should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your
>   site.

if I go to MVC controller action frist, and come to api action again, it works fine.

I am wondering how to solve this issue, and what is the best practice to handle user specified data with web api and MVC4, Thanks.

Comment: After re-implementing the override attribute for ActionFilterAttribute, it works fine now. This is due to MVC and webApi has different namespace for ActionFilterAttribute.

Comment: Tony, would you mind elaborating on your solution? I have the same issue...thanks.